# Blink a label inside a repeater C# ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a label inside the Repeater3. And I want the label to blink when the text of label is changed.

Sample code:

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <asp:Label ID="lblWindow" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Window") %>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblToken" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Token") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="windowID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("WindowID") %>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="departID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DepartmentID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

and

```
protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            //binding
        }
    }
```

Is it possible and how I do that? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "when the text is changed"? What is changing the text of the label?

Comment: yes sir when changing the text of the label. any idea sir?

Comment: You did not address my previous comment. Please re-read it and answer it in full.

Comment: @SandraHoward *who* is changing that label *how* and *when*? Those are important points to understand before you get anywhere with this

Comment: i have updatepanel that every seconds will update the data bound from repeater and when new data inserted that is the moment text of label will changed